# How to place C# Dll into toolbox and .NET Framework Components by Installation package?

Tags: c#, .net, components, controls

How do i place C# Dll into toolbox and .NET Framework Components by Installation package?

Answer (score 2):

By right clicking in the ToolBox you'll get Choose Items...

In the "Choose Toolbox Items" window Click on "COM Components" Tab

from there you can browse your DLL file and click OK

That DLL will be appeared in your tool box.

You have to choose an item from .NET Framework Components to add the built in Components in to your toolbox.